# Angular 2 - is index.html is a root file?

Tags: javascript, html, angular2-template

I am totally new to Angular 2 and started learning it 2 days back. I have used **'templateUrl'** property in one of my component so that clicking on some button creates tab view , code of which is written in some other html file named **'tabs.html'.**

Now in this new html file, I am calling a function **'openTab'** on click of a button. This function is written in same file - **'tabs.html'**. 
While executing the app, system is unable to find the function '**openTab' even though it is in same file.**

However, if I move this function to index.html, which is said to be a welcome file for angular 2 , **system is able to find the function**.

Why is this happening?
Should I write all the global functions in index.html?

Comment: Make sure the involved elements are member of the controller

Comment: `Should I write all the global functions in index.html?` - 500% no. You shouldn't be writing *any* functions in *any* HTML files - put them in your components and bind to them. If you don't know how to do that, I'd recommend reading [the official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

Comment: The index.html should contains your head and body tags. Then inside the body tag you create a new element. This element will be your placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

index.html is the default page. When you create a new project, you can find this in index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LPV</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<app-root>`tag is the name of the selector of the default app.component.ts file, so this is the app component which be called.

You can change the default page to show by replacing `<app-root>` by the selector of your component in the index.html, or you can create a router to redirect to your component, I advise you to follow this tutorial : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html

Comment: Thanks @Loic for your help. From your comment I understood that my app.component.ts has selector 'app-root', therefore it is redirecting to index.html. But what i should do if I want to write my specific function in some different html file or in the same file instead of writing it in index.html.

Comment: Not exactly. Your project loads the index.html by default. And you have to update the '<app-root>' tag and make the name of the selector of your new component if you want it to be called at page init. If your selector name is "myTabPage" then you have to replace "<app-root></app-root>" by "<myTabPage></myTabPage>